# template.setRetryPolicy(policy) is throwing syntax error

Tags: java, spring-batch, spring-retry

In my application I am calling web services. So I thought to implement Spring Retry mechanism to make processing more robust and less prone to failure. This is the first time I am using Spring Retry

I created a Application service class in which I am declaring RetryTemplate and setting RetryPolicy.

But it's throwing below syntax error

```
"Multiple markers at this line
- Syntax error, insert "Identifier (" to complete MethodHeaderName
- Syntax error on token ".", @ expected after this token
- Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodDeclaration"
```

Even If I use ctrl+space it's not showing setRetryPolicy() method.

Below is my class:

```
import java.util.Collections;

import org.springframework.retry.policy.SimpleRetryPolicy;

import org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate;

public class ApplicationServiceRetry {

    SimpleRetryPolicy policy = new SimpleRetryPolicy(5,Collections
            .<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean> singletonMap(Exception.class, true));
    RetryTemplate template = new RetryTemplate();
    template.setRetryPolicy(policy);  //it's throwing error here

}
```

I am referring http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/retry.html.
Here I am using Spring-retry 1.1.5.RELEASE.

Comment: Java code that isn't a field declaration (your first 2 lines, maybe unintentionally) can not exist outside of methods (or initializers). You'll have to put `template.setRetryPolicy(policy); ` in a place where it's legal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

??

```
template.setRetryPolicy(policy);
```

You can't just put arbitrary code there in a class - it has to be in a method, or an initialization block...

```
public class ApplicationServiceRetry {

    SimpleRetryPolicy policy = new SimpleRetryPolicy(5,
            Collections.<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean> singletonMap(Exception.class, true));

    RetryTemplate template = new RetryTemplate();

    {
        template.setRetryPolicy(policy);
    }

}
```